# Stop showing the recaptcha so many times! Once is enough in a short period of time

Tags: discussion, recaptcha

I open a few questions in multiple browser tabs from SO and start typing answers or comments and I understandably get hit with the first eCaptcha. OK so SO thinks I might be bot because I am submitting a few entries in a short period of time. I prove I am human. From that point every time I answer or comment, the annoying recaptcha pops up again. I just proved I am human. Stackoverflow needs to remember I am not a bot and not a bot which cracked reCaptcha. I am just a fast typing human! Probably intentionally producing friction to slow me down.

Comment: True story:  The CAPTCHA system is afraid of Jon Skeet.  This is how he answers 5,000 questions simultaneously.

Comment: Jon Skeet wrote a CAPTCHA parser.

Comment: A CAPTCHA caught Jon Skeet once... **ONCE!**

Comment: Not so fast wise guy. We need to make sure. Have you ever injured a human being or, through inaction, allowed a human being to come to harm?

Comment: @Randell: "I Robot" proved that your question isn't as definitive as you may think. ;)

Comment: I know this is an old question but I've been searching this exact thing.  For me it's the new image ones "select squares with vehicles, store fronts, gas stations etc..."  Sometimes I get asked 10 times in a row before it finally goes though.  What's up with this???

Answer (score 9):

The problem with your *I-proved-I'm-human* suggestion is that when a human solves one reCAPTCHA, they have free run of the system.

CHAPTCHAs are designed to verify **and throttle suspicious activity**. If you're getting reCAPTCHA'd that often, you can understand why that might be considered outside the normal use-case for the system.

If a single, human-solved CAPTCHA proves that someone is human from then on, it would open the system to a torrent of automated spam posts from that user. ReCAPTCHA simply slows down that process, making it *not* worth the effort for the spammer. It's a minor inconvenience under "normal use."

Comment: So how does that work? You bring up a browser and solve your first captcha as a human and then fire off your well configured bot pretending to be the same browser? I see how this works.

Comment: Sure. Even with a simple macro recorder using a browser, I could post a few hundred "buy my Viagra" ads an hour... if it wasn't for the Captchas. But that's low tech compared to -- as you call it -- a well configured bot.

Comment: ... and Captcha throttling isn't *just* for well configured bots. It also keeps the random neanderthal from going into a thread and filling the screen with "asdf"... "asdf"... "asdf"... comments and answers all over the place just because they can.

Comment: And don't forget we've actually seen someone spamming in exactly that way: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/02/new-question-answer-rate-limits/

Comment: Why didn't I need to solve a capture to submit this?

Comment: Or this immediately after?

Comment: Or even this one

Answer (score 2):

There are a few things you shouldn't be doing.

1. Doing **drive-by answers.**  *(this triggers a rate-of-answer flag)*.  If you can't put 2 minutes of consideration into an answer, that's not an answer of SE quality. Consider Twitter.
2. Opening up several windows at once, writing several answers at once, and **going down the tabs** hitting Post Your Answer Post Your Answer Post Your Answer.  *(This triggers a rate-of-answer flag)*.  Write one answer at a time, and submit it.
3. Starting to compose an answer, **walking away from it**, spending many hours doing other things on and off the site, then coming back.  *(this triggers a "stale answer" flag, which gets challenged extra hard, trust me!)* If your half-answer is not unfit to be seen, then consider

   - Post the answer
   - Comment "Still working on this..."
   - Delete the answer

This has a cool side-effect: deleted answers are visible to anyone with sufficient rep, alerting regulars that you have a work in progress, and cueing them as to the general direction you are going with the answer, so they don't double your work.  When complete, undelete, and delete your comment.

Comment: I just bumped in that one a couple of times as I started writing a question and had to move on to other things so I had to finish up later. Annoying but the question went through anyway. All of that being said, with an account with already over 200 questions and over 600 answers... is that really necessary? I suppose someone could have hijacked my question, but then they could as well create a new post with their crap.